# how to execute openrowset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, openrowset

I have tried this step for execute openrowset

```
use [master]
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1

reconfigure
go
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1

reconfigure
go

exec master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',N'AllowInProcess',1
go
exec master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',N'DynamicParameters',1
go
```

but when i tried do this

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0; Database=D:\FTP\data_kabupaten.xlsx; HDR=YES; IMEX=1',
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]') 
GO
```

a message is

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 The OLE DB provider
>   "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an
>   error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
>
> Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Cannot initialize the data source
>   object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server
>   "(null)".

Comment: make sure EXCEL is not open

Comment: yes data_kabupaten.xlsx is not open

Comment: use `Data Source` instead of `Database` in your connection string.

Comment: Checked file / path permissions for your DB user?

Comment: yes, i have give permission

Comment: it can execute now, but time execution is so long (1 hour more), so i cancel the execution :D

Comment: now i import one by one file to my db use SSIS (temporarily)